# dataframe has two column id and value pair. tranpose the 2 column keeping id

Tags: python, pandas

| id | Doct_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1021 | 355 |
| 2010 | 355 |
| 2010 | 358 |
| 6120 | 358 |
| 21201 | 358 |

Expected output from above table using python

| Doct_id | id_1 | id_2 | id_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 355 | 1021 | 2010 |  |
| 358 | 1021 | 6120 | 21201 |

```
id_list = df['Doct_id '][~df['Doct_id '].duplicated()]
t_rows = []
max_val_num = 0
for id_ in id_list:
    row = df[df['Doct_id '] == id_]['id'].tolist()
    t_rows.append(row)
    if len(row) >= max_val_num:
        max_val_num = len(row)

df_transform = pd.DataFrame(t_rows , columns=['col_'+str(i) for i in range(max_val_num)])  
print(df_transform.head(100))
```

I tried the above code but it transfer only id but i would like to have table like below.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please see [Ask] to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
df[''] = df.groupby('Doct_id').cumcount() + 1
df = df.pivot(index='Doct_id', columns='', values='id').add_prefix('id_').fillna('').reset_index()
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Doct_id    id_1    id_2     id_3
0      355  1021.0  2010.0         
1      358  2010.0  6120.0  21201.0
```

Comment: But this throws an error, ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape